# Hashcat: "Failed to parse hashes using the 'native hashcat' format"

Tags: security

I tried to use Hashcat on a Word password-protected doc, but I got this error:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\hashcat-5.1.0>hashcat64.exe hashcat -a 0 -m 9600 --username -o pass.txt hash.txt rockyou-withcount.txt
hashcat (v5.1.0) starting...


* Device #2: This hardware has outdated CUDA compute capability (3.0).
             For modern OpenCL performance, upgrade to hardware that supports
             CUDA compute capability version 5.0 (Maxwell) or higher.
* Device #2: WARNING! Kernel exec timeout is not disabled.
             This may cause "CL_OUT_OF_RESOURCES" or related errors.
             To disable the timeout, see: https://hashcat.net/q/timeoutpatch
nvmlDeviceGetCurrPcieLinkWidth(): Not Supported


nvmlDeviceGetClockInfo(): Not Supported


nvmlDeviceGetClockInfo(): Not Supported


nvmlDeviceGetTemperatureThreshold(): Not Supported


nvmlDeviceGetTemperatureThreshold(): Not Supported


nvmlDeviceGetUtilizationRates(): Not Supported


OpenCL Platform #1: Intel(R) Corporation
========================================
* Device #1: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz, skipped.


OpenCL Platform #2: NVIDIA Corporation
======================================
* Device #2: GeForce GTX 760, 1024/4096 MB allocatable, 6MCU


Failed to parse hashes using the 'native hashcat' format.
No hashes loaded.


Started: Fri Dec 28 19:04:28 2018
Stopped: Fri Dec 28 19:04:28 2018


C:\Users\User\Desktop\hashcat-5.1.0>
```

The file hash.txt:

> $office$*2013*100000*256*16*caeeddcc432ce81fc337e7ebeaf222df*2e7ed78069479490aa256e9889b7405f*c2ece9296ccf8523e5c9f3bce0ea5d4a31f5df78d8ccfd7909b009e636dd17e0

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old, but the problem here is that you have to remove the `--username` option if the `hash` file doesn't contain the name of the document that you're trying to crack
For example: 

Using the option `--username` with the below hash file will lead to normal output without parsing errors
hash.txt:

> File name.doc:
> $office$*2013*100000*256*16*caeeddcc432ce81fc337e7ebeaf222df*2e7ed78069479490aa256e9889b7405f*c2ece9296ccf8523e5c9f3bce0ea5d4a31f5df78d8ccfd7909b009e636dd17e0

And using `--username` with your file which contain only the hash of the document will lead to parsing error.